# how to trace all functions inside interface or specific function in class aspectJ in android

Tags: java, android-studio, aspectj

I found it was too difficult for me to figure out AspectJ in android java
My purpose is to traceback inside functions if the data has been transferred correctly
In my AspectJ class called LogAspect

```
@Aspect
public class ActivityLifecycleLogAspect {
   

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.abcd.MyClass.getName*(..))")
    public void logActivityLifecycle(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ABCD:------------- " + joinPoint.toLongString());

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.abcd.Myinterface..*(..))")
    public void logActivityLifecycle(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Interface Function Tracing:------------- " + joinPoint.toLongString());

    }
}
```

so I like to know two things
how to trace all functions inside the interface
how to trace a specific function inside a class

I think I have a problem targeting the functions and classes and interfaces..
I have no clue how this works... plz help me!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised to edit your question and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then I will be glad to answer your question. Thank you. Secondly, it is pointless to add any code to a `@Pointcut` method. It will never be called. Only advice type annotations like `@Before`, `@After`, `@Around` can trigger actions. There you either directly specify pointcut expressions or refer to ones defined in `@Pointcut`s. Please do read an AspectJ tutorial in order to learn more about the correct syntax.

Comment: my mainactivity has its testing function and it is empty. I called testing function on create inside main activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, your comment does not help me and your question is still far from an MCVE. If you have difficulties explaining your problem, please let code speak. Did you read and understand my hints about your no-op aspect?